# Windows Phone (8) default appbar icons

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, appbar

In the example appbar on my Windows Phone application I can see this line of code added a button:

```
ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

What I find interesting is that the icon is sourced from "/Assets/AppBar/". Are there any of the other standard Windows Phone appbar icons in there and if so is there a list or reference somewhere for me to use?

Comment: Which example are you using? you have to add images if you want to use them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have installed visual studio then you can get these files from here

**`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons`**

Answer (score 10):

If you open the ApplicationBar Buttons collection editor, you can access to the list of the available icons. When you select one, it will be automatically added to the project:

[image]

Comment: The "editor" this refers to is Visual Studio. Just go to properties with your xaml item selected.

Answer (score 3):

Other icons which are not included in the Windows Phone SDK can be found on [Modern UI Icons](http://modernuiicons.com).